# view binary contents of .bin file

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, bash, powershell

I created a program in C++ that simulates a simple files system creating a 20 sector 64KB block memory allocation but I'm having trouble verifying contents after manipulation. Friend was using xxb -b "filename" in terminal on his mac. Trying to find the windows equivalence. It's stored in .bin file.

Comment: I am not aware of any command that would parse a binary input and display the binary in any format.  Most of the time if a Windows user wants something like this they have to create it yourself.

Comment: A "hex editor" is what you're looking for. There's one called HxD which I've used, it should provide what you're looking for. @Ramhound Why is is this off topic? Also you're comment is flat out wrong. There are literally dozens of programs that do exactly this.

Comment: @Drew - I thought the author was looking for a built-in solution that could be used within the command prompt.  While I agree this question is requesting a software recommendation, I had nothing to do with the question being closed, you would have to asked the moderator who closed it.

Comment: There is no hex viewer/editor built into Windows. Windows is for normal people, administrators, and programmers. None of these groups need hex viewers. Only reverse engineers need hex. The Windows debuggers can of course show hex but they need to be downloaded. Here's an intro to them https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/brief-introduction-to-windows-debugger.html.